# how to extract jsonarray in java when two arrays in output

Tags: android, arrays, json

How to retrieve the ids array from the following JSON Object.

```
{"bets":[{"bet":[{"gid":"10","Result":null}]},{"bet":[{"gid":"7","Result":null}]},{"bet":[{"gid":"3","Result":null},{"gid":"6","Result":"2"}]},{"bet":[{"gid":"6","Result":"2"},{"gid":"4","Result":"1"}]},{"bet":[{"gid":"6","Result":"2"},{"gid":"4","Result":"1"}]}]}{"ids":["9c9nogs6of","ank4kt3gqo","jfgrt91nk4","a8qmoq7v4q","8mov5ita1t"]}
```

I've tried

```
     allids = jObj.getJSONArray("ids");
```

which should work because it works with `jObj.getJSONArray("bets");` however I receive this error in logcat `E/Buffer Error﹕ Error converting result org.json.JSONException: No value for ids`

PHP FILE

```html
  <?php
        // get tag
   $param= $_POST['param'];
   $bet = explode("//",$param);
   $allbetslength = count($bet);
   $ultresponse["bets"] = array();
   $idresponse["ids"] = array();
  for ($x = 0; $x < $allbetslength; $x++) {
   $indid = substr($bet[$x],0,10);
  array_push($idresponse["ids"], $indid);
   $bet[$x] = substr($bet[$x],10);
  

   $id = explode(",",$bet[$x]);
   $arrlength = count($id);
   //  include db handler
         require_once 'include/Check_Bets.php';


        $db = new Check_Bets();
        $response["bet"] = array();


   for($y = 0; $y < $arrlength; $y++) {

        $result= $db->checkuserbets($id[$y]);
        array_push($response["bet"], $result);
        }
   array_push($ultresponse["bets"], $response);
   array_push($ultresponse["bets"], $idresponse["ids"]);
       }
        echo json_encode($ultresponse);

    ?>
```

Comment: you have invalid json , is this the right json ? use 
http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ to validate json

Comment: you have `}{` near here : `}{"ids":["9` , but shoud be ","

Comment: let me update with the php file which produces this

Comment: you use echo `json_encode($ultresponse);  echo json_encode($idresponse);` it is 2 objects, so you can put both in one new jsonObject and then echo

Comment: you can do that. but it depends what output you need. i would probably just use something like this: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a28ec5d48f269cccc5865ab831a8e731f9e3e32a